# How to organize Symfony 3 Code to work with complex JSON API endpoints?

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, architecture

I'm currently working on a project with some complex business logics on Symfony 3.

I want to use JSON API to provide communication between my front and backend. Previously, I developed very badly-designed APIs, and didn't thought much on how to best process them, e.g., when I had (as example)

*/resource?include=field1,field2*

I justed parsed these included fields in my Controller Action. As a result, after some time the app's code always became difficult to read, reuse and maintain.

But now I'm interested in what is the best practice to process queries, say, like:

*/users?fields[users]=id,first_name,last_name,avatar_src&include=comments&fields[comments]=author,text,likes_count,reposts_count,created_at&sort=-comments.created_at&filter[users][region_id]=3*

There are some more resources in the app, each providing many different fields (some of which need to deal with MySQL Joins to be retrieved), sorts, filters. Moreover, each resource can be extended with **included** query param to specify that we want to get additional resources.

I thought to somehow centralize parsing of incoming request in a kind of EventListener, which will collect all the data, map it to Doctrine Entities and build some sort of DQL Schema. Controller action will catch it to return a Response.

Should I try this? Or maybe this is also a very bad solution? Could you recommend something on how to correctly deal with this?

Comment: You should take a look at [ApiPlatform](https://api-platform.com/). It's based on symfony and it's gonna be the main api solution for SF4. Also you should do some research about [REST](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an impression, that you are trying to turn your API in something like "SQL over HTTP". That's will obviously create something of clusterfuck, due to the amount of optional parameters.

> #### <sup><sub>You probably should read [this article](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) and watch [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) on the given subject.</sub></sup>

I personally prefer the endpoints to always return the same fields and use the parameters, when I need to [expand](https://stormpath.com/blog/linking-and-resource-expansion-rest-api-tips#resource-expansion) one (or more) of those fields, or when the endpoint contains a collection and I want to filter/paginate the results.

That way the "parsing" of user's request becomes a lot simpler.

It also seem, that your "include" field provides a way for user to reach in the DAL and directly fiddle with persistence. You end up with layers leaking the abstraction.